# IIS7 rejecting POST requests with 400 error

Tags: iis-7, http, iis

I have a web application that is supposed to handle post requests from SAP.

This has been working fine at other customers with win2k3 systems (IIS6) and win2k8 (IIS7) systems.

However, on this specific customer's site, IIS responds with a 400 response, without calling my aspx page. In fact, I don't even see it appear in the w3c log for the virtual directory.

I do see the request using Network Monitor, so I know no firewalls and the like are eating the request, and as far as I can tell, all of the fields of the request are valid (there is "content-length", it looks correct (this is a sending of a 28K tiff file - which isn't MIME encoded, curiously enough now that I think of it...)

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found the answer, and it isn't wonderfully useful for non-SAP users.

The program making the request was a utility used by the SAP Front-End client called saphttp.exe. Turns out, the version the customer had was one that SAP reported having EXACTLY this issue - badly formed POST requests. I copied my version of the utility to the customer site and it worked.

Mark it up to SAP wackiness.

Answer (score 2):

You could check the HTTPERR log on that server. Maybe this blog post contains a hint how to solve the problem:

[ASMX POST request fails with HTTP 400 erro when content-length size increases](http://blogs.msdn.com/jaskis/archive/2009/04/19/asmx-post-request-fails-with-http-400-error-when-content-length-size-increases.aspx)

> First stop was to look at HTTPERR log on IIS box,  Invalid verb error was report in it:
>
> ```
> 2009-03-09 21:30:53 10.1.48.56 42676 10.1.48.53 80 HTTP/0.0 Invalid - 400 - Verb -
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Any chance that it's being handled by another site?  Try a 'break test'.  Stop the site and see if the response changes.

Without a log entry you can't tell what the sub-status code is, which would help troubleshooting further.

Comment: I moved the asp.net application to its own site (it was in a MOSS2007 site), but no change.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a new server? If it's a default installation it could be that ASP.NET was not enabled. Check in Role Services if ASP.NET is checked in Web Server / Application Development:

[IIS enable ASP.NET role http://learn.iis.net/file.axd?i=2231](http://learn.iis.net/file.axd?i=2231)

Comment: ASP.NET is enabled because GET requests to the .aspx page are handled.

Answer (score -1):

This happened to me and it turns out that the feature I had to enable was parent paths.  Bit of a bogus error message!